# Angular: Change the class member names dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

In the angular ts file, I have a const like below

```
const baseMaps = {
            Map: "test 1",
            Satellite: "test 2"
    };
```

And I want to set Map and Satellite member names dynamically.
Below will not work but I need a solution something like below.

```
const mapText = "Map";
const baseMaps = {
            mapText : "test 1",
            Satellite: "test 2"
    };
```

Can anyone guide me on how to do this?

Comment: The value of a const should be assigned at compile time and it never changes once the application is started. You can achieve the desired behaviour by replacing const to let or var.

Comment: It won't work by simply replacing var or let.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `[...]` you can dynamically infer the key of an object.

You can do the following:

```
const mapText = "Map";
const satelliteText = "Satellite";
const baseMaps = {
           [mapText] : "test 1",
           [satelliteText]: "test 2"
    };
```

Comment: It works. Thanks much.